# Pressure in kg's from snowshoes

Tags: forces, pressure

I'm planning on making a hiking trip to a remote location. There will be approximately 1.5m of snow, so I'll be using snowshoes. However, the area that I'm supposed to climb used to be a battlefield. From an old colonel I learned that the area has been demined, but there still may be mines that were left behind. I also know exactly what type of mines may be there, and all of them activate upon applying a force of 5kg.

So, my question now is, how do I calculate how much force will be transferred through the snow from the top to the bottom ground where the mines are? For an example, the snowshoes are 68.6 cm x 21.6 cm in size, my weight with all equipment would be 115kg, the density of the snow ranges between 200-300 kg/m^3, with a height of 1.5 m.

I've tried searching online, but physics is not my strong suit, so I thought I'd ask here for help.

Comment: Sounds like obfuscated homework, but -> " all of them activate upon applying a force of 5kg" -> Not any more.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon , Maybe it does, but this is actually the most important piece of detail needed for my trip. I'm not asking for anyone to solve it for me, I'm just asking how to do the calculations, since the last time I had physics was back in high school. Didn't understand the last part though, what do you mean with "Not any more"?

Comment: Mines that used to have 5kg activation force when made will now have "???" activation force. If old it will sometimes be < 0 . You need to provide details of age of mines. | 200 kg/m^3 snow with 1.5m depth will weigh 5kg over an area of 130mm x 130mm. What is the trigger area? | Your weight places 115kg/(.686 x .216) = 716 kg/m^2. If you have two snowshoes that large it's about 350 k/m^2.  You will probably sink.  If I take a sealed plastic bag of snow I'd not expect it to float superbly. This suggests your stated  snow density is far too low.

Comment: Snow will set off all the mines, or you won't. Don't jump. | FWIW - the question as stated is ludicrous. Snow depth varies greatly and 1.5m is either homework or a useless guess. Snow density is vvvvvv suspect.  Watch for avalanches.

Comment: Are you really willing to risk your life on assumptions about mines and snow, etc? If you are really going on this trip, for God's sake consult an expert on the area. If you are not going, get your physics textbook out and start learning some physics. We don't do calculations just to please people.

Comment: I don't have specific details, but the mines were planted somewhere between 1998-1999. There are two types of mines there, PMA-2 and PMR-3. The trigger area for PMA-2 is roughly 3x3 cm's in the form of a star. PMR-3 is a round mine, with a diameter of 10.3cm, where the whole top side is the trigger area. 
As for the density of the snow, it can vary between 200-300 and 350-400, but that is not a fixed variable and can't be checked until december when the snow falls. 
Regarding the depth, that's what I was told by a guy that already visited the place a couple of years ago.

Comment: @sammygerbil I'm still in the phase of gathering information, and no, I won't go without having all the necessary information, which is why I started here. Believe me when I say that this is not something I take lightly, but I've come to a point where I don't know how to proceed (due to lack of expertise in physics), which is why I'm asking for help.

Comment: How to proceed is to ask a local expert who knows the area, the snow, the mines, etc. The opinion of someone who knows the area well is far more reliable and valuable than a calculation by a Nobel Laureate in Physics.

Comment: Homework or not, I think this is a great question and I'd love to see the answer. But I'm terrified by the idea of OP taking these calculations and just waltzing through a minefield (!!!) secure in the knowledge that just because some back of the envelope calculations say it's probably okay, the mine's won't have a damaged trigger, some heavy material lying on top of them, or some other issue that makes them blow up unexpectedly. You're a brave man, buddy.

Comment: @sammygerbil I've asked a veteran who was posted there to describe the terrain, which paths are safe(r) to use, which ones to avoid, etc. I also asked him about the mines, and his answer was the same as the colonels; the area has been demined, but of course, a few may have been left behind, though not on the paths but rather in the forest around. With this in mind, I'll still take every precaution I can, hence my question. But as I said, this is still in the planing phase, lots and lots of more angles have to be covered before I go on this trip.

Comment: @Superbest I'm aware of the decay of landmines over the years, as well as other factors involved, and that you can never be 100% sure that nothing will happen. However, this is something I must do for personal reasons, and I'm willing to take the risk, although I'm trying to significantly lower it by planing and gathering as much information as I can. However, I learned that others have been there before and went unharmed. One was an official, and I doubt they would have let him venture there if there had been a great risk of injury/death. Still, one cannot be to careful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can answer this - at least not reliably.  The snow will pack down under your snowshoes.  The mine trigger will not.  So as the snow packs down under your weight, your full weight could easily come down onto the mine trigger.  the thinner and fluffier the snow, the more likely this is.  If you've ever stepped on a broken or cut-off branch sticking up through the snow, you've experienced this.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! 
The location is at an altitude of 1600 meters above sea-level, and the snow usually falls in December-January, and stays there until the end of March, as far as I know. I'm planning on going in February, in order to avoid fresh snow with less density. Is there a way to simulate this in real life before the trip? A friend suggested that I place an egg at a set distance below the snow, but I'm not sure if he was serious or not.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be quite different based on the type of mine. Some are triggered by tiny pins, others by a few centimeters wide pressure plate. The pin designs have a small pin that protrudes just above the surface, that triggers the explosives when depressed. The pressure plate designs have a circular pressure plate held up by a spring that requires *X* amount of force/weight to depress, and can be buried under the soil.

*68.6cm x 21.6 = 1481.76cm2*

*115kg / 1481.76cm2 = ~0.077kg/cm2*

Given you figures, your shoes will be exerting a pressure of *~0.077 kg/cm2*. Assuming you step on a mine with a pressure plate that has a *5cm* radius, you'll be exerting

*(3.14159  x  5cm  x  5cm) x ~0.077 kg/cm2 =*

*(~78.5cm2) x ~0.077kg/cm2 =*

**~6kg** of weight down onto the mine. I hope it's a dud.

Snow compaction is very difficult to model, but as an anecdote I'll cite that my feet always seem to go straight down into the snow, and leave a hard packed footprint. On top of that, if it's light fluffy snow the particles aren't going to form strong lateral linkages, so again all the load is going to go straight down. You should expect pressure figures near the ones I listed.

Also, consider that over time the pressure-plate spring is going to weaken. Out of the factory they might have triggered at 5kg, but now they might only need 1 or 2.

Comment: Thank you! 

I'll post the same what I posted in the answer above, the snow will most likely not be light and fluffy, but rather compact. How does that change things? 

Also, yes, I'm aware of the decay of landmines over time, especially in a harsh environment, that was among the first things I was told when asking about them.

Comment: @CobraAn The only honest answer I can give you is "I don't know." There's a couple positives, though. First is that pin-typed mines probably won't be triggered because the snow will just move around the pin. Second is that the snow will keep you somewhat safe from Bounding mines (basically a spring-loaded grenade that pops out of the ground and detonates at waist height.) The snow will keep the grenade from flying up and should absorb at least some of the shrapnel.

Comment: I know for a fact that there are no Bounding mines there, "just" PMA-2 and PMR-3, although they should have been cleared. Also, I found another, longer, way which wasn't mined, so that will probably be the one I'll end up using. Anyway, thank you a lot for the help!